# How to send message for registrarion processing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know how to send the message to a particular number when he entered his number.

how the registration process going?

My question is.

1.user enter his mobile number
2.he/she hit the registration button

then i need to send the message(some random code granted by  server-php side)to that number.

for this i need web service ?

Comment: go to that link http://www.sms-integration.com/how-to-send-one-time-passwords-from-php-102.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this alternate way but with out `web service` you cant do this

***Reason** : user has use the more than one Device, he given the alternate number of another device , you can't handle*

> **Choice-1**

**Step-1**

inside your app create the `randomarc` number and when user hit the registration button  send the random number with your profile details to backend with the help of webservice.

**Step-2**

In backend side with the help of `SMTP` in which random number you already send to backend , the backend developer send the random number to particular mobile number.

**Step-3**

finally In your own hand your random number number is available , in here no need of webservice ,if user entered the same number move the next step else show the alert thats all.

> **Choice-2**

**Step-1**

when user hit the registration button  send the profile details to backend with the help of webservice and get the random Number on success response.

**Step-2**

In backend side with the help of `SMTP` the random number to particular mobile number.

**Step-3**

finally In your own hand your random number number is available , in here no need of webservice ,if user entered the same number move the next step else show the alert thats all.

Comment: can u provide any sample code in objective c. @Anbu.Karthik